# When working with FontAwesome for react, where do I add library.add()?

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I haven't coded for quite some time and am having difficulties trying to get some font awesome icons into my header. I've read the instructions on the Fontawesome website and still having issues. I've clearly missed something. After importing the packages I'm struggling to find where I add `library.add()` function into my code. There's a console error that reads "could not find icon"

This is basically what my code currently looks like:

```
  import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
     import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
     import { faCheckSquare, faCoffee } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
     import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
     import './header.css'

     library.add(fab, faCheckSquare, faCoffee)

     export default function Header(){

       return (
        
          <>
            <div className = "header">
                <h3 className = "heading">heading.</h3>
                <li className = "header-nav">
                <a href="true" id="contact">contacts<FontAwesomeIcon icon="faCoffee" /></a>
                </li> 
            </div>
        </>
      )
   }
```

Comment: Can't you just use `<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} />`?

Comment: Yeah not sure why I was overcomplicating it. Cheers!